# Do I need to port forward for communication between two machines on the same network?

Tags: java, sockets, port, portforwarding

I'm planning on writing a relatively simple client-server socket program in Java, where the server will run on one machine and the client on another machine (both wired on the same network).

[Link two computers with Socket in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121987/link-two-computers-with-socket-in-java).
From the answer to the above question, I believe that I will need to port forward (not an issue as I know how), but this does, however, go against my intuition as I am under the impression that port forwarding would only be necessary if I needed to connect to a service/machine/whatever on my network from a remote machine (not on the network).

So my question is, do I need to port forward for communicating between two machines on a local network? If yes, why?

Comment: Nope, pretty sure you're right about port forwarding only being necessary for outside-network connections. If they're on the same network all you have to provide is the other device's local/private IP address :)

Comment: I'm not sure what leads you to the conclusion that that question suggests port-forwarding is necessary. That seems to be a confusion introduced as part of the comments on the answer, which suggests that maybe the person writing the answer thought that client and server in that situation where in different networks (instead of maybe a local firewall (eg Windows Defender) blocking a port).

Comment: https://erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/inet-pages/arp.html

Comment: @dantechguy I thought so, thank you for clarifying :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My confusion came from the person writing the question claiming that changing the "localhost" in their code did not fix their issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the machines are in the same network, you don't need to configure port-forwarding. Even if the machines are in different networks, you don't need to configure port-forwarding, assuming those machines have routable IP addresses (and there is no firewall blocking that access).

Port-forwarding is only relevant when communicating to - for example - a home network that has a single IP address, where there are multiple machines on an internal network, and the local router that is visible to the internet needs to perform NAT (Network Address Translation) to map between the local network and the big bad internet. Port-forwarding makes sure that an internet visible port is forwarded to the IP address of a machine on the internal network.

What you do need to take into account is the possibility that local machine firewalls (e.g. Windows Defender) may block access without explicitly whitelisting the application and/or port.

Comment: My intuition was right about how ports work then. Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Comment: Another case is if you run (code inside) a virtual machine, or several, that share(s) the host/real machine's network interface; depending on the virtualization you use this may or may not be labelled NAT, but you need to configure which incoming ports go to which VM(s). Similarly docker (and things based on it) needs to forward incoming connections, although usually you configure it as part of each container rather than separately.